# WSO2 - Governance registry API

Tags: api, registry, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to document web service operations using WSO2 governance registry specifically api manager. What I am suppose to provide for the following fields - provider, name, context. I am not able to find any description of these fields any where on the help document.

Is there a more appropriate option to document web service operations? i.e rest services schema, operation name, description etc?

-ap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM100/Adding+an+API

provides information for you query. The link provides comprehensive documentation on WSO2 APIM.

Regards,
/Nuwan